# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[19] = 30522 is not in [0, 30522)

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, tensorflow-hub

what I am doing: adding special tokens using hugging face and their tokenizer and using keras tensor-flow hub model

I get this error when I add special token to the model:

```
   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[19]=30522 is not in [0, 30522)[[{{nodedncc/keras_layer/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/bert_model/StatefulPartitionedCall/word_embeddings/Gather}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_43492]
```

though same code worked fine in google colab only if I am connected GPU only?.

I don't know if there is incompatibility problem in some how? why it only work in colab?

Answer: there is a bug and special tokens only work on GPU

Comment: Can you please provide reproducible code so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23698 the problem is clear: when you add new vocabulary in the model using tokenizer, the model does not read the updated vocabulary file unless you are in GPU mode in colab .. if you want i can share reproducable code but maybe after two weeks